# Getting GPS coordinate at click point

Tags: autodesk-forge

im creating a forge viewer and trying to create an extension that alows me to click a point on the 3D model and display the coordinates at that point in a pop up window or similar.. i cant seem to get the geolocation extension to work at all. does anyone know of any tutorials or sample codes that do this?

cheers Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide more details about the problem you met, it will help us understand it quickly.

However, you may check out the below sample code demonstrating how to convert mouse-clicking point to geolocation that works with `Autodesk.Geolocation` extension. Also, refer my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59997471/7745569) to configure your Revit model to make the `Autodesk.Geolocation` extension works properly.

```js
(function() {
  class GisTool extends Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.names = ['gis-tool'];
 
        // Hack: delete functions defined *on the instance* of the tool.
        // We want the tool controller to call our class methods instead.
        delete this.register;
        delete this.deregister;
        delete this.activate;
        delete this.deactivate;
        delete this.getPriority;
        delete this.handleSingleClick;
    }
 
    register() {      
      console.log('GisTool registered.');
    }
 
    deregister() {
      this.viewer.unloadExtension('Autodesk.Geolocation');
      this.geoTool = null;
      console.log('GisTool unregistered.');
    }
 
    async activate(name, viewer) {
      this.viewer = viewer;
      this.geoTool = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Geolocation');

      if (!this.geoTool.hasGeolocationData())
        alert( 'No GIS data found in current model' );

      console.log('GisTool activated.');
    }
 
    deactivate(name) {
      console.log('GisTool deactivated.');
    }
 
    getPriority() {
      return 1; // Or feel free to use any number higher than 0 (which is the priority of all the default viewer tools)
    }
 
    handleSingleClick(event, button) {
      if (button === 0 ) {
        // const hitPoint = this._intersect(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        // const geolocation = this.geoTool.lmvToLonLat(hitPoint);
        const canvasX = event.canvasX;
        const canvasY = event.canvasY;
        const res = this.viewer.clientToWorld(canvasX, canvasY);
        const geolocation = this.geoTool.lmvToLonLat(res.point);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.point));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(geolocation)); //!<<< the geolocation you want
        return true; // Stop the event from going to other tools in the stack
      }
      // Otherwise let another tool handle the event
      return false;
    }

    _intersect(clientX, clientY) {
      return this.viewer.impl.intersectGround(clientX, clientY);
    }
  }

  class GisToolExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
      super(viewer, options);
      this.tool = new GisTool();
    }
 
    load() {
      this.viewer.toolController.registerTool(this.tool);
      console.log('GisToolExtension loaded.');
      return true;
    }
 
    unload() {
      this.viewer.toolController.deregisterTool(this.tool);
      console.log('GisToolExtension unloaded.');
      return true;
    }
 
    onToolbarCreated(toolbar) {
      const controller = this.viewer.toolController;
      this.button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('gis-tool-button');
      this.button.onClick = (ev) => {
          const isActivated = controller.isToolActivated('gis-tool');
          if (isActivated) {
            controller.deactivateTool('gis-tool');
            this.button.setState(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.INACTIVE);
          } else {
              controller.activateTool('gis-tool');
              this.button.setState(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button.State.ACTIVE);
          }
      };
      this.button.setToolTip('GIS Tool');

      this.group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('gis-tool-group');
      this.group.addControl(this.button);
      toolbar.addControl(this.group);
    }
  }
  Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('GisToolExtension', GisToolExtension);
})();
```